# Can I see the code for the script applied when recording UI interaction in Instruments?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Is there a way to see the code for the script that Instruments uses when you record UI interactions?  Can I view this code in a way similar to the scripting used for UI Automation?

Answer (score 3):

The source for the UI test (the javascript), or...? It's not clear from your question.

This is apple's documentation for how to record a UIAutomation test script:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewInstruments/NewFeatures42/NewFeatures42.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010950-CH4-SW8

In the center of your split Instruments window you should see something marked "Trace Log". Click on that, it's a pulldown that will have "Script" as a choice. Selecting that will take you to the script editor and allow you to record. Recording a script does NOT use the jolly red, candy like button at the upper left of the Instruments screen. It uses the smaller, jolly, red, candy like button at the bottom of this script editor pane.

I'd post a screenshot, but I don't have enough points. Hope that helps!

Comment: >> "Recording a script does NOT use the jolly red, candy like button at the upper left of the Instruments screen. It uses the smaller, jolly, red, candy like button at the bottom of this script editor pane."

Thank you so much for pointing that out - I've been Googling for ages trying to work out what I might be doing wrong/was about to post a question here :) (and now I look more closely it *does* say that in the documentation, I was blinded by the giant candy like record button in the top left)